# Do objects/effects render when they cannot be seen in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, memory, graphics

Obviously I hope the answer to this is "no, it will not be rendered." The reason I ask is my code base I inherited is rather large, and uses up huge chunks of memory. I still don't know what all is causing the issue.

I was recently looking at the Template inheritance for items because there is default template for most usual controls. Textboxes, buttons, etc, all have default templates that were copy/pasted from each other for the most part. The issue with this is the original was done in Expression Blend I believe and ended up with a slew of settings that actually cause no change.

My question is that there are certain graphical effects being set in the Template behind these objects that appear all over the place that don't visually do anything but are still set. One of these is a gradient in the background, but there are others. Could this be contributing to the memory usage? granted these are very small things, but I know from certain debugging I have done that its loading pretty much everything right from the get go. All the pages at least have what they can have processed, processed. I don't know how its handling that but as far as my project is concerned they exist and have to be maintained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverlight controls don't really typically support UI virtualization (which happens to be the official term for what you are describing).

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.aspx

Some do though. DataGrid doesn't for example. If this doesn't help, please provide more info about what controls you're using.

To sum it up: it depends on the container.

Another thing you can try is to implement this: http://kent-boogaart.com/blog/virtual-paging-in-silverlight

Comment: I am 99% sure there are no distinctly labeled Virtualizing containers used. Its Stackpanel, Grid, Canvas, itemscontrol, border, etc.

I'm also a little worried about implementing them on a wide scale since I had an instance where virtualization for a Telerik product broke functionality. 

What is most likely occuring is there is a definition for a gradient, it is all over the place and is in the background definition of the template (say a button template). Its not so much that my stuff is on top of eachother, its more like I have a border with a background but I fill the contents too